# how to return an html with javascript method with twig render method

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

i want to render a controller when clicking on button i use this javascript method

```
function getPopoverContent(input) {   
   return {{ render(controller("LeymaxReserveBundle:Reserve:showAddReserveModal",{'iduser': user.id,'token':'1238','idreserve':'0'})) }};

    }
```

but it causes an Illegal exception ,and same thing with quotes ::

```
 return "{{ render(controller("LeymaxReserveBundle:Reserve:showAddReserveModal",{'iduser': user.id,'token':'1238','idreserve':'0'})) }}";
```

here is my acion::

```
public function showAddReserveModalAction($iduser, $token, $idreserve) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('LeymaxContactBundle:User')->find($iduser);

        return $this->render('LeymaxReserveBundle:Reserve:addReserveModal.html.twig',       array(
                    'user' => $user,
                    'token' => $token,

        ));
    }
```

how can do it?

Comment: have you tried piping your twig expression using raw? 
E.g. 
return "{{ render(controller("LeymaxReserveBundle:Reserve:showAddReserveModal",{'iduser': user.id,'token':'1238','idreserve':'0'})) | raw }}";

Comment: soory but , it returns an ilegal exception also , thank you for your help but it doesn't work .

Comment: the exception :: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: are you returning from your controller in JSON format (is you controller a service?)

Comment: no i'm returnig an html , i'll edit the post to show you the action .

Comment: I think you are passing the parameters wrong, Try this format: {% render "MyBundle:Controller:function" with { 'arg1' : 'value1', 'arg2' : 'value2' } %}

Comment: error ::Unexpected token "name" of value "with" ("end of statement block" expected) in

Comment: That error is in your view not in your controller

Comment: yes it's in the view , the line that contains the embedded javascript ( the return statement as described in the post)

Answer (score 0):

U should use :

```
 return "{{ render(controller('LeymaxReserveBundle:Reserve:showAddReserveModal',{'iduser': user.id,'token':'1238','idreserve':'0'})) }}";
```

U are now breaking up your javascript at the moment :

```
return "aaaa"bbbb"aaaa"; <-- invalid syntax
```